# SUB Special Char needs to be removed from Column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Need to remove SUB Special Char from Column in Teradata, Have tried using below replace commands but it's not working.

```
regexp_replace(column, X'1A', '', 1, 0, 'i')
OREPLACE(Column, X'1A' , ' ')
```

Have tried to remove it with alphanumeric value but some other char are getting removed with it, need to remove only that SUB char from the string.

```
 regexp_replace(column, '[^0-9a-z]', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the *error character* is a bit tricky in Teradata, any explicit or implicit conversion results in

> 6706 The string contains an untranslatable character.

If your input column is LATIN you must ensure that *all* parameters for  `oTranslate` are LATIN to avoid conversion. If the input is UNICODE *all* parameters must be UNICODE.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt
 (
   col_latin   VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET Latin
  ,col_unicode VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET Unicode
 ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
  
INSERT INTO vt
 (
   'hello' || Chr(26) || 'world'
  ,Translate('hello' || Chr(26) || 'world' USING latin_to_unicode WITH ERROR)
 );
 
SELECT 
   OTranslate(col_unicode -- UNICODE
             ,Chr(26)     -- LATIN
             ,' '         -- UNICODE
             )
FROM vt; 
-- fails
             
SELECT
   OTranslate(col_latin   -- LATIN
             ,Chr(26)     -- LATIN
             ,' '         -- UNICODE
             )
FROM vt;
-- fails

SELECT 
   OTranslate(col_unicode -- UNICODE
             ,Translate(Chr(26) USING latin_to_unicode WITH ERROR) -- UNICODE
             ,' '         -- UNICODE
             )
  ,OTranslate(col_latin   -- LATIN
             ,Chr(26)     -- LATIN
             ,Translate('' USING unicode_to_latin) -- LATIN
             )
FROM vt;
-- returns both 'hello world' successfully
```

Comment: Still getting error using the OTranslate command for UNICODE.
Below are the values present in the column, which are causing issue want to remove the special char only from it. Is there any way to replace the char to blank.

    01:(20)
    02:(20)
    01:(20)

Comment: See my modified answer. If it's still failing you might have an old version of `oTranslate` in `syslib`, switching to `td_sysfnlib.oTranslate` should solve this issue.

Comment: Still it's getting same error with td_sysflib.oTranslate

Comment: 01:SUBSUB(20SUBSUBSUB)

Comment: 02:SUBSUBSUBSUBSUBSUBSUBSUBSUB(20SUBSUBSUB)

Comment: the string comes as above, the SUB is the special char, have pasted for reference as it's not supporting in the commenting box

Comment: Can you show a `char2hexint(column)` for a failing row?

Comment: 30313A1A1A2832301A1A1A29

Comment: there are spaces upto 500 char at the end

Comment: That's LATIN, the LATIN version should work.