# How to remove untranslatable characters from a string in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am  querying to one table, but I am getting result as:

> SELECT Failed 6706 The string contains an untranslatable character.

I don't know which column is having untranslatable character.

Can anyone help me how to find the untranslatable character and remove that.

eg:- string:- `'boys sizes S-3XL, 28-36. girlss sizes S-3X. Kids NB-5T,Sleeperwear XS-XL. Mens wear The Find, slippers.'` (in between string some untranslatable characters are present)

Output should be:- `boyss sizes S-3XL, 28-36. girlss sizes S-3X. Kids NB-5T,Sleeperwear XS-XL. Mens wear The Find, slippers.`

Comment: Last I checked TeraData <> SQL Server - any reason you have tagged both?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67922293/2527905

Comment: while creating table design  latin,Unicode has not given for column, so this wont work..tq please assist how to proceed now...

Comment: Note there are 2 forms suggested at that link, one works for LATIN fields and one for UNICODE